# How to reset a counter column to zero in a table every month

Tags: java, date, calendar, scheduler

I have a column named

`duty_counter` to store the no of persons working for every month. 
`reset_date` to store the last reset date.

i get the reset_date using the following sql and set it to the curr date

```
select distinct TO_CHAR(reset_date,'DD')as day,TO_CHAR(reset_date,'HH24')as hour,TO_CHAR(reset_date,'mi')as min from hr_mgt;
```

Consider the output here as Date 12 , Hour 18 , minute 00.

Lets say at 5th of every month , the `duty_counter_column` should be reset to zero only once.

```
    Calendar reqDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    reqDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.valueOf(4));
    reqDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(23));
    reqDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(59));
    Calendar currDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    currDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.valueOf(12));
    currDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(18));
    currDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(00));
    System.out.println("reqDate :  " + reqDate.toString());
    System.out.println("currDate :  " + currDate.toString());
    if (currDate.equals(reqDate) || currDate.after(reqDate)) {
        System.out.println("Reached the Req Date , reset the counter");
    }
```

But currently whenever the scheduler runs after 5th of every month, it is resetting the duty counter. How to make this code to run only once at 5th of every month?

Thanks for your suggestions and time.

Comment: I suggest you store the last month and year the scheduler was run. So after the fifth of the month, compare to the stored value to see if the scheduler has already run this month.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using the `Calendar` class in 2017? It is long outdated. I recommend that instead you look into [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API (also known as JSR-310)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is much nicer to work with (and will easily catch if you by mistake set hour of day to 59).

Comment: What is the datatype of `reset_date` in the database? I would recommend you retrieve it as a date or date-time type from the database rather than as individual numbers. For example `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` or `Instant` depending on the exact information available in the database (the three mentioned types are from `java.time`).

Comment: @Ole.V.V reset_date is a Date datatype ..i am using jdk1.7 and have never used java.time..

Comment: In that case, I think the best thing is to retrieve a `java.sql.Date` from the database.

Comment: With JDK 1.7 it’s still worth considering using JSR-310 through [the ThreeTen Backport](), the backport of JSR-310 to Java 6 and 7. Then use [DateTimeUtils.toLocalDate()](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html#toLocalDate(java.sql.Date)) to convert your `Date` to a `LocalDate`, which is what you will want to work with.

Comment: As Ole V.V. suggests, it is definitely worth the bother of adding the *ThreeTen-Backport* library to a project running in Java 6 or Java 7. The old legacy date-time classes are a terrible mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

The `Calendar` class you are using is long outdated. [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), the modern Java date and time API also known as `java.time`, is generally much nicer to work with.

```
/** On what day of each month should the count be reset? 1..28 */
private static final int DAY_OF_MONTH_TO_RESET_COUNT = 5;
/** In what time zone should above day-of-month be interpreted? */
private static final ZoneId timeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Pontianak");

public static void resetIfDue() {
    // substitute reset_date from DB here
    LocalDate lastResetDate = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.DECEMBER, 5);

    LocalDate nextResetDate = lastResetDate.plusMonths(1)
                                .withDayOfMonth(DAY_OF_MONTH_TO_RESET_COUNT);
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(timeZone);
    // "not after today" means today or before today
    if (! nextResetDate.isAfter(today)) {
        System.out.println("Reset the count and update the reset_date in the database");
    }
}
```

Do you agree that this code is not only shorter but also more elegant and clearer to read than yours?

On Java 1.7, get ThreeTen Backport and import classes from the `org.threeten.bp` package, and the above code will work. Get the reset date as a `java.sql.Date` from the database; `ResultSet.getDate()` will give it to you, for example. Then immediately use `DateTimeUtils.toLocalDate(sqlDateFromDatabase)` to convert it to a `LocalDate` for the above code. With Java 8 you could get the `LocalDate` directly from the result set.

You will need to decide whether to update the reset date to the calculated next reset date, today’s date or something else. I am leaving that to you.

I recommend you give explicit time zone for time zone sensitive operations like getting today’s date. So please fill in your time zone if it doesn’t happen to be Asia/Pontianak. To use the JVM’s time zone setting, use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. Be aware that the setting may be changed by other parts of your program or other programs running in the same JVM, so if one day you experience that the update happens too early or too late, this is a possible source of error.

### Links

- [ThreeTen Backport home page](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [Oracle tutorial trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Comment: resetIfDue function calls every time on day 5 of every month automatically? or i need to triger event for this?

Comment: No, the call does not happen automatically. You need some scheduler or trigger to call it (in the question the problem was that the scheduler was running more often than the reset was wanted).